# Chrome Browser read from serial port

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, serial-port

I'm writing a web app for a client and need to get data from a serial port from a scale used for weighing things.

This is an intra-web project, so I can specify that we're using Chrome. I see that Chrome apps have the ability to talk to the serial port. But I want direct access from Javascript in the browser, not from an app. How do it do it?

One option I've thought about is to use the HTML5 FileReader, and point it to the serial port. Since the serial port looks like a file on Linux it might work.

Any thoughts from anyone?

Comment: If possible, you could run a small node server that reads from the port. Then stream that to the browser. If Chrome API allows that, you can build an extension that talks to your JS in place of a node server.

Comment: While it looks like a file, I don't think it can be read like a normal file. You would need a middleware that will communicate to the port and relay that to the browser. For instance you could have a background application running that constantly reads the port and writes to an actual file which FileReader could then use. Or as Joseph mentions use something like a node server to be the middleware.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the extension route, first then if that doesn't work the mini-server route.